# Is intake of 1 tablet of 500 mg vitamin C per day unnecessary?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, supplement, vitamin-c

1 tablet of vitamin C has 500mg which is 556 %DV according to the label. I know that daily limit to feel healthy without symptoms is around 1000mg.

Label also says that serving size is 1 chewable tablet and to chew 1 tablet up to two times daily.

***Question:*** **Is there a point in taking 556 %DV of vitamin C per day as a chewable tablet?**

Or should I just break the tablet into 2-4 pieces and take them on separate 2-4 days?

Comment: I am new here, so if I should rather ask this kind of question on Biology/Chemistry Stack Exchange, please let me know ;)

Comment: Are you actually asking "what is the point of taking more vitamin C (or any vitamin) than the 'daily value'"? That is a fairly generic question, whereas the way you've worded it it looks like a request for medical advice.

Comment: @Esther I understand that there is no point in taking more than %DV per day, but I have a bottle of vitamin C tablets, it's not the cheapest and if there are no reasons to take whole tablet per day - I don't see a reason why I would do that. In case 556 %DV is good for your body because it will absorb easier or better then I would take a whole tablet daily. Or half a tablet each 12h if that makes more sense.

Comment: It sounds like you *are* asking if there is a point then. So maybe you can [edit](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/posts/31746/edit) your question to reflect that. Also your numbers are off: did you mean 100mg (about 1/5 of 500mg, which is ~500%DV)? Because 1000mg is *double* 500, so you would need 2 per day to reach that amount?

Comment: @Esther when I mentioned 1000mg - is UL when you won't start to feel symptoms of overdose, what I was referring to is The Upper Limit (UL) per day. I read that here - https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/16053 .

Comment: According to your link, UL Is 2000mg/day

Comment: @Esther True, sorry, wrong link. Here is the one I had in my head - https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/82/25989 .

Comment: Could you clarify how your question is not answered by [the Q&A](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/16053) you linked?

Comment: This is both a medical advice question and a diet/nutrition question. I think it should be closed.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ “there is no point in taking more than %DV per day” maybe there is a point.

Comment: In this rare instance, I don't necessarily see this as a medical advice question @CareyGregory as it is pointing at the %DV and asking the point in taking a dose that high. However, there is a similar question with an answer, which helps to understand possible reasons for such a dose. Anything more will be too localised in my mind. Therefore, this is a duplicate unless the OP can explain why they don't see this being the case.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Okay, I'll go with the third reason of being a duplicate.

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't have any objections. From other answers about absorption rates and %DV I can deduce how much mg would be sufficient per day. Since absorption rate isn't always 100% then I can assume that it makes sense to take in more than 100%DV in mg. I guess this question would require a more sophisticated answer to be sufficient as an explanation, with data about age, height, weight, body fat % and correlation of mg ingested to mg absorbed by the body, along with charts that show it.